# Is it possible for me to check if the variable will be assigned with a value?

Tags: c++, variables, linked-list, operator-precedence

I have a matrix that is a nested linked list. I want to use operator overloading so that I can do `matrix(x,y)` to access a 'node'. The problem is, how do I check if that `int&` will be assigned with a value? The reason for this is because I do not want to create a 'node' unless it is being assigned with a value.

> Structure:
>
> Class `Matrix` -> when initialized (ex. `matrix matrix(10,10)`, where `10x10` are the dimensions) the nested linked lists do not create the nodes in memory, they wait until the node is being modified, so if there is no 'node' then spacer value is 0.
>
> `int &operator() (row index, column index)` -> when this is triggered (`matrix(x,y)`) then it basically searches for the linked list row (if not found it creates one with that index), it then searches the linked list column (if not found then it creates one with that index), after all this is done it return the data variable by reference.

So basically, I only want to do the top if I know the 'node' will be assigned with a value / initialized.

examples (NOTE: 'node' does not exist yet)

``
matrix(4,5) = 18; // return int& so that it can be assigned with 18
matrix(4,5);      // do not create 'node' because it will not be assigned with a value

```
Note: this is just background info, please don't code everything and give me the answer. All I want to know is if there is a way that before `operator()` is called it checks for assignment so I know it will be assigned a value and won't just return for no reason.

Please don't tell me to do `operator(row indx, column indx, data)`, if possible I would like to keep the format of `matrix(row,column) = x`.
```

Comment: You cannot know that. But a sometimes used technique is not to return `int&` but instead return a custom object that stores the matrix and indexes. You can detect if this object is assigned to, and you can overload operator int on this object as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

What you should do is mark `operator()` (or whatever you use to access element by index) as `[[nodiscard]]`, so that anybody who tries to call it without using the value will get a compiler warning.

This doesn't let you distinguish between reads and writes, so reading a non-existing element will create that element.

If you don't want that, you need two separate functions for reading and writing elements, something like `.set(x, y, value)` and `.get(x, y)`.

---

Some might suggest to return a helper class from `operator()`, with an overloaded `operator=` (writing the element) and `operator T` (reading the element). But this is bad and evil, because `operator T` isn't always invoked automatically (e.g. when passing the object to a function template), and when it doesn't, your users will be confused.

Comment: I wish points could be given in fractions. +1 for `[[nodiscard]]`, -1 for saying that using a helper object is "bad and evil", since it is a very common technique to use.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Only the `operator T` part is evil in this case. `operator=` is fine. I haven't seen the former being used this way in any libraries I used (or at all, outside of a few SO answers).

Answer (score 2):

Here's the intermediate object technique in outline

```
class Matrix
{
    friend class MRef;
    MRef operator()(int i, int j) { return MRef(*this, i, j); }
};

class MRef
{
public:
    MRef(Matrix& m, int i, int j) : m(m), i(i), j(j) {}
    MRef& operator=(int n) const { code to set value in the matrix }
    MRef& operator=(const MRef& m) const { return operator=((int)m); }
    operator int() const { code to get value from the matrix }
private:
    Matrix& m;
    int i;
    int j;
};

Matrix m;
m(1,2) = 3;
int x = m(3, 4);
m(5, 6) = m(7, 8);
```

I completely agree with HolyBlackCat, this code has issues, but any solution is a compromise. It's up to you to pick which compromise you want to go with. This technique has convenient syntax, but personally I'm not sure how important that is. I'd go for separate getters and setters.